# How to replace key + null value, Python

Tags: python, regex, string, text, python-3.4

I need to replace with `""` (i.e. completely remove) any `[key]: null` from a string. Example:

```
s = 'a: 1, b: null, c: null, d: 0, e: null, f: 0.3'
```

with desired output has `b: null`, `c: null`, `e: null` removed:

```
'a: 1, d: 0, f: 0.3'
```

where commas can be removed with `s.replace(', ,','')`

Is there a clean/robust way to do so? Naturally, key names can change, but those with values `null` need to be removed.

I suppose `re` (regular expressions) package can be of help, but I have not used it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
r = re.sub(r'\b\w+:\s+null(,\s*|$)', '', s);
```

**Output:**

```
a: 1, d: 0, f: 0.3
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ9iI8/1)

Comment: or maybe simpler:  re.sub(r"[a-z]: null, ", "", s)

Comment: But `a: null` can be at last also like `'w: 2, a: null'`

Comment: That's neat. What if the separator is not a `,`, but `\n`? Is there a way to search specifically for `: null` ?

Comment: Ok. This seems to work: `re.sub(r'\b\w+:\s+null(|$)', '', s)` . Thanks for the link to awesome RegEx tool!

Answer (score 2):

```
s = 'a: 1, b: null, c: null, d: 0, e: null, f: 0.3'
# split with "," and then ":"
dataList = [d.strip().split(':') for d in s.split(',')]
# check if the tuple's second value is string "null"
dataListFilter = filter(lambda x: x[1].strip() != 'null', dataList)
# join back the results
result = ', '.join(map(lambda x: x[0] + ': ' + x[1], dataListFilter))
print result
```

**SUGGESTION**:
I would suggest using a better data structure than a string for such kind of data. Generally hashes (Python dictionaries) would suit if you have control over the data.

Comment: Thanks. This is not a data structure, but a YAML dump to screen (without further loading) :) All I need at this point is to clean up the dump a bit. There is probably a way to strip `null` keys with `yaml.representative`, but it's still in the works :)

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'a: 1, b: null, c: null, d: 0, e: null, f: 0.3'
r=''
for e in s.split(','):
    if (e.split(':')[1]!=' null'):
        r = r+ ',' +e

print (r[1:])
```

Comment: without regex, why dont you use dictonnary ?